# Como popular um model a partir de um DataReader no C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Desculpe a ignorância sobre essa pergunta. No PHP havia a possibilidade de usar o "FetchClass" do PDO que pegava todos os resultados de uma tabela e os jogava em um objeto de determinada classe, porém não encontrei nada similar no C#.

Pelo DataReader eu teria que pegar cada propriedade e jogar no model manualmente, o que eu queria fazer é que isso fosse automático, já que os nomes da tabela são iguais ao do model.

No momento eu achei a Entity Framework muito avançada e gostaria de entender alguns conceitos mais baixos do .NET antes de prosseguir.

Teria como popular um model a partir de um DataReader ou DataSet?

Comment: Não conheço uma forma de mapear o retorno da transação para um objeto de forma automagica. Tu teria que construir de qualquer forma uma extensão que fizesse isso, ou usar um ORM. Tu poderia usar reflection, mas se achou o EF avançado, vai ficar um pouco mais complicado.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão @Aline - encontrei a Dapper e elaborei uma resposta sobre ela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não. Automaticamente não tem como.

Uma opção é usar um pouco de *reflection* e fazer este trabalho. Não vou postar uma resposta com isso porque não me parece o intuito desta pergunta, principalmente por causa desta parte

> No momento eu achei a Entity Framework muito avançada e gostaria de entender alguns conceitos mais baixos do .NET antes de prosseguir.

O que você pode fazer, é criar um método que aceite um `IDataRecord` e retorne uma instância do modelo.

Como por exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Pessoa Criar(IDataRecord record)
    {            
        return new Pessoa
        {
           Id = record["id"],
           Nome = record["nome"]
        };
    }
}
```

A partir disso, você pode criar um método genérico que leia o `DataReader` e retorne uma coleção de dados.

```
public IEnumerable<T> LerDados<T>(IDataReader reader, Func<IDataRecord, T> CriarObj)
{
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return CriarObj(reader);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
         reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

O uso seria algo assim

```
var pessoas = LerDados(dataReader, Pessoa.Criar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o usuário LINQ respondeu, diretamente não é possível.

No entanto usando a sugestão da Aline de usar uma ORM encontrei, o pacote "Dapper" e "Dapper.Contrib", que são extremamente simples e não necessitam de muitas configurações. Para mapear os objetos é excelente, mesmo que você não goste de utilizar uma ORM, pois ele permite usar suas queries da forma tradicional.

Exemplo de uso:

```
public class Cidade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Uf { get; set; }
    public int Ativo { get; set; }
}
```

E aqui é onde mapeamos o resultado de qualquer Query (exemplo).

```
List<Cidade> listCidades;
Cidade model = new Cidade { Nome = "São Paulo" };

using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Config.GetConString()))
{
    con.Open();

    var cidades = con.Query<Cidade>
    (
        "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE nome LIKE @nome",

        new
        {
            nome = "%" + model.Nome + "%"
        }
    );

    listCidades = cidades.ToList<Cidade>();

    con.Close();
}
```

Para queries mais simples para insert, update, delete, é possível usar as extensões do Dapper.

```
T Get<T>(id);
IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
int Insert<T>(T obj);
int Insert<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Update<T>(T obj);
bool Update<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Delete<T>(T obj);
bool Delete<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool DeleteAll<T>();
```

Neste exemplo utilizei o MySQL e o Dapper funcionou perfeitamente.

Também é possível utilizar o padrão Repository para agrupar estas queries em suas devidas classes e poupar as operações genéricas usando um repositório genérico.

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected MySqlConnection con;

    protected int timeout;

    public RepositoryBase(MySqlConnection con, int timeout = 10)
    {
        this.con = con;
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    public long Insert(T model)
    {
        return con.Insert<T>(model);
    }

    public bool Update(T model)
    {
        return con.Update<T>(model);
    }

    public bool Delete(T model)
    {
        return con.Delete<T>(model);
    }
}
```

E para as classes filhas.

```
public class CidadesRepository : RepositoryBase<Cidade>
{
    public CidadesRepository(MySqlConnection con, int timeout = 10) : base(con, timeout) {}

    public List<Cidade> Search(Cidade model)
    {

        var cidades = con.Query<Cidade>
        (
            "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE nome LIKE @nome OR uf LIKE @uf",

            new
            {
                nome = "%" + model.Nome + "%",
                uf = "%" + model.Uf + "%"
            }
        );

        return cidades.ToList<Cidade>();
    }
}
```

Vale lembrar que após instalar os pacotes via Nu-Get é necessário incluir as referências no código e no projeto.

```
using Dapper;
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
```

> Dapper: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper